# Relation $\left(B+\frac{B}{2}\right)^{2}<A^2<\left(B+\frac{B+2}{2}\right)^{2}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Problem :

Let : $A,B\in\mathbb{N^{*}}$

Where :

$$\left(B+\frac{B}{2}\right)^{2}<A^{2}<\left(B+\frac{B+2}{2}\right)^{2}$$

So :

$$\left(B+\frac{B+1}{2}\right)^{2}=A^{2}.....** $$

I see in solution $B=\operatorname{odd}$ but why ?!

$B$ must be odd ? Why not even ?

And how $**$ ??

I have already to see your solution

Comment: I think there is something missing from your question. It should be $A^2$ instead of $A$

Comment: If $B$ is even then what can you say about $(B+1)/2$? Can it be an integer?.

Comment: It's basically like,  $x^2 < A^2 < (x+1)^2$ (letting $B+ B/2 = x$). As @Andrei said, it should be $A^2$.

Comment: @SL_MathGuy I'm sorry yes $A^{2}$ but why $B$ odd ? Can you explain to me ?

Answer (score 3):

We proceed by way of contradiction.

Suppose $B$ is even. Then $B +\dfrac{B}{2}$ is an integer (positive), say $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So is $B+\dfrac{B+2}{2}$, which is equal to $n+1$. Now we have, $$n^2 < A^2 <(n+1)^2$$. But, does there exist such an integer $A$?

If not, then $B$ must be odd.

Let $B = 2k+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z_+}$ . Then, we have $((3k+1)+ 1/2)^2 <A^2 <((3k+2)+1/2)^2$. Since $A \in \mathbb{Z_+}$ , $A$ must be $3k+2$ since that's the only positve integer lies between $(3k+1)+1/2$ & $(3k+2)+1/2$ .

So, $$A = 3k+2 =B+ (B+1)/2$$

Comment: thanks! So if i try $B=2k$ i will get contradiction